# sql IN operator with text array

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to find string values in text array using SQL query.

Suppose I have:

```
id       location
1        {Moscow,New york}
2        {Mumbai}
3        {California,Texas}
```

I want to find id whose location is `Moscow`.I used:

`select id from table where location in ('Moscow');` but get error:

```
ERROR:  malformed array literal: "Moscow"
LINE 1: select id from table where location in ('Moscow');
DETAIL:  Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.
```

I am using Postgres.

Comment: look at this documentation  8.14.5. Searching in Arrays https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/arrays.html

Comment: also this https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-array.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Searching in `Array DataType` you can use the `ANY()`

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE 'Moscow' = ANY(location);
```

Live Demo

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/a6c3a/2

Comment: location is of type `text[]`

Comment: Check Now @lupin

Comment: Welcome!! @lupin

Answer (score 2):

For DataType=Array, you can use the method=Any.

```
select id from table where 'Moscow' = Any(location)
```

As the document [which describes DataType=Array](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/arrays.html):

> 8.14.5. Searching in Arrays
>
> To search for a value in an array, each value must be checked. This
>   can be done manually, if you know the size of the array.

or use [the method = Any](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-comparisons.html):

> 9.21.3. ANY/SOME (array)
>
> expression operator ANY (array expression) expression operator SOME
>   (array expression) The right-hand side is a parenthesized expression,
>   which must yield an array value. The left-hand expression is evaluated
>   and compared to each element of the array using the given operator,
>   which must yield a Boolean result. The result of ANY is "true" if any
>   true result is obtained. The result is "false" if no true result is
>   found (including the case where the array has zero elements).

Comment: I have to say posting an answer by Stackoverflow App is really not easy.

Answer (score 0):

select id from demo where location like '%Moscow'%'

Comment: location is of type `text[]`